# Python Flask 404 errors

Tags: python, flask

I've been following up on some tutorials on how-to-build-restful-apis-with-python-and-flask. I encountered a few problems initially such as:

Issue 1 (resolved I think)
Python running a web server in a virtualox vm listening on localhost only. I since changed the script to run specifically on a host ip and port so that it accessible to serve GET requests from an external browser.

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app(config_filename):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_filename)
    
    from app import api_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api')

 #   from models import db
 #   db.init_app(app)

    return app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app("config")
    app.run(host='192.168.56.92',port=5000,debug=True)
```

Issue 2:

I am still getting the 404 errors below when I do a curl or
try to load from an external browser http://192.168.56.92:5000/api/Hello

```
 * Running on http://192.168.56.92:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 339-215-805
192.168.56.1 - - [04/Nov/2020 16:57:22] "GET /api/Hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -
192.168.56.1 - - [04/Nov/2020 16:57:46] "GET /api/Hello HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

If you guys can point the error, then that'll be great.

Thank You

Comment: Please share the code where `api_bp` is defined, the error must come from there

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted the issue, and thanks for pointing it out although not obvious. The issue is was with a resource class called Users that is imported in the run class.

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restful import Api
from resources.User import User

api_bp = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = Api(api_bp)

# Route
api.add_resource(User, '/User') ==> Problem was here.
```

I corrected the endpoint to have an upper case U` whereas previously was '/user'. It is now working.

Thanks All